# How to replace long chain of forEach{} statements in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, foreach

I am dealing with a situation where I receive a general object in my activity that has many relations with other objects from my room database. I need to access a low level object and have to iterate multiple times with forEach, like:

```
items.forEach{ item -> 
   item.categories.forEach{ category ->
      category.dataTypes.forEach{ dataType ->
         dataType.configValues.forEach{ value ->
            if (value) (...) 
         }
      }
   }
}
```

It feels pretty annoying to have such a chain of statements like this. It looks like bad code somehow. Is there a way to reduce this boilerplate in Kotlin?

Comment: depends on what you do inside... but `flatMap` combined with `filter` might work out... basically it depends whether you still need the values from the outer loops or not.....

Answer (score 2):

How about flat mapping before?

```
items.flatMap { it.categories }
    .flatMap { it.dataTypes }
    .flatMap { it.configValues }
    .filter { ... your filter ... }
    .forEach { ... }
```

The chain is effectively still there, but it is flattened.

Comment: Each time you invoke `flatMap` on a collection, you create a new collection, this may impact badly on a performance. So I recommend invoking `asSequence` first and `collectionMap` instead of `flatMap` where `collectionMap` is `inline fun <T, R> Sequence<T>.collectionMap(crossinline transform: (T) -> Collection<R>) = flatMap { transform(it).asSequence() }`